# behaviour of varible /array

Tags: c, arrays, storage

I have two programs:

```
program 1:    
----------
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    return 0;
}

program 2:
----------
#include<stdio.h>
int a[10];
int main()
{
   return 0;

}
```

1) Can both programs allocate memory for array **a[10]**.
2) If both programs are done in allocating memory, in which memory segment (I mean data segment or stack segment) is memory allocated.
3) Can anyone explain what the difference would be between program 1 and program 2?

Comment: The main difference is: global variables are always initialized to `0`, in the first case `a` contains garbage.

Comment: in second case . why not **int a[10]** doesn't come to external variable declaration. @AlterMann

Answer (score 4):

program 1:

- the array is allocated on the stack
- because it's on the stack and not initialized, it will contain whatever is on the stack; we call it garbage.

program 2:

- the array is a global array and is allocated in the .data data section(unless otherwise specified in the linker file)
- it actually goes in the .bss section which is part of the .data (usually). This is where all uninitialized global variables end up.
- it is automatically initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes! both the programs will allocate memory for array a[].
2. There are 4 segments- **(Global seg+ Constant seg)=(Data section)**
   In the global declaration it is in Global data section. And the local one is in Stack segment because a function instantiate pushing a frame into tha stack which contain state informations like variables,..etc and return point from of the function from where the function is called.

   +---------+
   | stack  .. |
   +---------+
   | Heap ...|
   +---------+
   | Globals|
   +---------+
   | Const...|
   +---------+
   |  code ...|
   +---------+
3. Now in the first case it is in Stack segment. In the second case in Globals segment of memory.
   The stack segment's array has scope over it's function body. It will be alive until the function is alive.
   But the global one will alive until the program ends. Now here as the function is main() then these two will have same lifetime.

   The initial value of global int variable is 0. But local ones will contain garbage values(unless initialized).